# Not able to save object using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

> INFO: HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hb_student_tracker?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC]
>   Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException:
>   Could not set field value [POST_INSERT_INDICATOR] value by reflection
>   : [class com.luvjava.hibernate.demo.entity.Student.id] setter of
>   com.luvjava.hibernate.demo.entity.Student.id  at
>   org.hibernate.property.access.spi.SetterFieldImpl.set(SetterFieldImpl.java:72)
>   at
>   com.luvjava.hibernate.demo.CreateStudentDemo.main(CreateStudentDemo.java:33)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set int field
>   com.luvjava.hibernate.demo.entity.Student.id to
>   org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper$2

error comes when saving student object in CreateStudentDemo.class

**CreateStudentDemo.class**

```
package com.luvjava.hibernate.demo;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.luvjava.hibernate.demo.entity.Student;

public class CreateStudentDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //create session factory
        SessionFactory factory=new Configuration()
                                   .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                                   .addAnnotatedClass(Student.class)
                                   .buildSessionFactory();

        //create session object
        Session session=factory.getCurrentSession();
        System.out.println("before try block");
        //save object

        try {
            //begin transaction
            session.beginTransaction();
            System.out.println("Creating student object..");
            //create object
            Student theStudent=new Student("Ravisher","Singh","rvsingh3213@gmail.com");
            //save object
            System.out.println("Saving Student Object...");
            session.save(theStudent);  **This is line from where exception starts**
            System.out.println(" afterSaving Student Object...");

            //commit changes
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            System.out.println("commit Done");
        }
        finally {
            session.flush();
            session.close();
            factory.close();
        }

    }

}
```

**This is Entity class**

```
package com.luvjava.hibernate.demo.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;


    @Id
    @Column(name="first_Name" )
    private String firstName;

    @Id
    @Column(name="last_Name")
    private String lastName;

    @Id
    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    public Student() {
        System.out.println("In default constructor");
    }

    //Constructor using fields
    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        System.out.println("arg constructor.");
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", email=" + email + "]";
    }




}
```

**This will be hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- JDBC Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hb_student_tracker?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC</property>
        <property name="connection.username">hbstudent</property>

        <property name="connection.password">hbstudent</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool settings ... using built-in test pool -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- Select our SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Echo the SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Set the current session context -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Remove@Id from firstName, lastName, email and have a try. If it's composite primary key then you should move those into separate class and refer that inside Student class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need only one @Id annotation in your entity class
Here is how your entity should look

```
@Entity
@Table(name="student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="first_Name" ) <--- first_Name, this value MUST MATCH WITH WHAT YOU HAVE IN YOUR DATABASE
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_Name")<--- last_Name, this value MUST MATCH WITH WHAT YOU HAVE IN YOUR DATABASE
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    public Student() {
        System.out.println("In default constructor");
    }

    //Constructor using fields
    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        System.out.println("arg constructor.");
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", email=" + email + "]";
    }




}
```